# Databricks - All records from Dataframe/Tempview get removed after merge

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-sql

I am observing some weired issue. I am not sure whether it is lack of my knowledge in spark or what.

I have a dataframe as shown in below code. I create a tempview from it and I am observing that after merge operation, that tempview becomes empty. Not sure why.

```
val myDf = getEmployeeData()
myDf.createOrReplaceTempView("myView")

 // Result1: Below lines display all the records 
 myDf.show()
 spark.Table("myView").show()

// performing merge operation
val sql = s"""MERGE INTO employee AS a
        USING  myView AS b
        ON a.Id = b.Id
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *"""

 spark.sql(sql)
 
 // Result2: ISSUE is here. myDf & mvView both are empty 
 myDf.show()
 spark.Table("myView").show()
```

**Edit**

getEmployeeData method performs join between two dataframes and returns the result.

```
df1.as(df1Alias).join(df2.as(df2Alias), expr(joinString), "inner").filter(finalFilterString).select(s"$df1Alias.*")
```

Comment: What's the definition of `getEmployeeData`?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy: Its a very long method. But In short I can tell you that, it performs join between two dataframes, Something like this:

df1.as(df1Alias).join(df2.as(df2Alias), expr(joinString), "inner").filter(finalFilterString).select(s"$df1Alias.*")

Comment: Isn't it anyhow based on `employee` table?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy : No. We have raw table. Which just compares the employee table and identifies the newly inserted and updated records.

Comment: *"Which just compares the employee table"* - so it does depend on it, yes? The point I'm digging towards to is that dataframes are lazy and are reevaluated on every use. In your case everything you have in `getEmployeeData` is evaluated both before and after the merge and can be different if any of dependencies changed.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy ohhh got your point. That sounds interesting. Is there a way to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataframes in Spark are lazily evaluated, ie. not executed until an action like `.show`, `.collect` is executed or they're used in SQL DDL operation. This also means that if you refer to it once more, it will get reevaluated again.

Assuming there's no other background activity that can mess up, apparently your function `getEmployeeData`, depends on `employee` table. It gets executed both before and after the merge and might yield different result.

To prevent it you can [checkpoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#checkpoint():org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) the dataframe:

```
myView.checkpoint()
```

or explicitly materialize it:

```
myView.write.saveAsTable("myViewMaterialized")
```

and later refer to the materialized version.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the points that @Kombajn zbozowy said related to Dataframes in spark are lazily evaluated and will be reevaluated again if you call action on it once more.

I would like to point out that, it is normal expected behavior and might not have to do anything with the merge operation.

For example, the dataframe that you get as an output of the join only contains inserts and you perform those inserts on the target table using dataframe write api, and then if you run the df.show() command again it would show you output as empty because when it is reevaluating the content of the dataframe by performing join it won't get any difference and will not output any records...

Same holds true for merge operation as it also updates the target table with insert/updates and when you rerun it won't show any output rows.